# .htaccess - Matching Env Variables in Rewrite Rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to **match** the words 'blogs' and 'news' in the following `url` according to the detected language via `htaccess`.

the url:

```
http://localhost/es/noticias
```

the language detection (working):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(es)\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(es)/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=LANG:%1,E=NEWS:noticias,E=BLOGS:blogs]
```

the rule (not matching ENV:BLOGS nor ENV:NEWS)

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(%{ENV:BLOGS}|%{ENV:NEWS}) index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

How to **match Env Variables** in `Rewrite Rule`?

EDIT 1 - the extended language translation

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(es)\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(es)/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=LANG:%1,E=NEWS:noticias,E=BLOGS:blogs]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(en)\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(en)/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=LANG:%1,E=NEWS:news,E=BLOGS:blogs]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(fr)\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(fr)/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=LANG:%1,E=NEWS:nouvelles,E=BLOGS:blogosphere]
```

Comment: I'm trying to get a condition to match when the ENV variable APPLICATION_ENV is *not* 'development' .. i.e.

`RewriteCond %{ENV:APPLICATION_ENV} !^development`

...but it seems to have the opposite effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with a dollar at the end `RewriteCond %{ENV:APPLICATION_ENV} !^development$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `RewriteRule` you need to use `RewriteCond` for matching env variables. See this code snippet:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGS} ^blogs$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:NEWS} ^noticias$
# some RewriteRule here
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

`RewriteRule` on the other hand is used for matching request URI only.

Comment: ok understood. I want to translate those words according to the detected language and match the translation with various url structure (having different RewriteRules) is it technicaly possible Anubhava?

Comment: Yes I suspected that you had some complex requirements but since question was just about use of ENV variables therefore I restricted my answer to that only. Having said that I request you to create a separate question detailing these ENV var checks you're trying to do and I will try my best to answer that.